# Excel - identify due date based on multiple frequencies of given dates

Tags: excel

I have table of frequency with amount:

```
name    start_date      end_date    frequency(M)    Amount
A       11 Nov 22       11 Nov 23   6               220
B       15 Nov 22       23 Jun 23   3               500
```

and a date table. Is there anyway using Excel formulas to identify due dates of these frequencies and sum up all due amounts, like:

```
Date            Amount
10 May 23       0
11 May 23       220
12 May 23       0
13 May 23       0
14 May 23       0
15 May 23       500
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

u can calculate the dates in the same row. the first date calculated would be referring to the start date and every subsequent dates to be calculated would be based on the previous date calculated

so, if your above first table is put in cells from A1 to E3,
the formula in cell F2 should read as: `=IFERROR(IF(EDATE($B2,$D2)>$C2,"",EDATE($B2,$D2)),"")`
and formula in cell G2 should be: `=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(F2,$D2)>$C2,"",EDATE(F2,$D2)),"")`

you will next need to pull formula in cell G2 towards right

and copy and paste formula in row 2 in row 3 onwards

to get sum of all the due amount you may next do a sumproduct function of the dates in formula and the amount column